# MPI(MPI 3.0 standart) implementations that supports SDM debugging

Tags: eclipse, debugging

Im searching for MPI (MPI 3.0) implementations that supports SDM debuging. I found that MPI simple program(e.g. MPI C/C++ Pi) which is using MPI implementation libraries can not be debugged by SDM if you use MPI 3.0 implementations of OpenMPI and MPICH2. Can you name me MPI implementations (MPI 3.0) that supports SDM debugging?

I found that Open MPI (1.7.1-1.8.1) does not support SDM debugging. The same thing I have with MPICH2 (1.5).

Comment: What is SDM?...

Comment: @DeerHunter,[link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PTP/designs/sdm) . I tested OpenMPI(1.7.5-1.8.1),MPICH2(1.5) programs. No one of this MPI implementations supports SDM debugging